# lock screen widgets is not Working and it is not displaying anything

Tags: java, android, xml

> I'm developing screen lock widgets or Lock Screen programmatically. I got some good ideas from Stackoverflow previous questions regarding this, and I did some thing well, but when I run that code, there is No Exception and Error. but when I run it shows nothing.
>   what I want is when user click on widgets it  locks the screen.
>
> Manifest.xml file

`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ASSIST" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".NewAppWidget"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/new_app_widget_info" />
    </receiver>
</application>
```

`

> MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
final static int ENABLE_ADMIN = 1;
final static int SUCESS = -1;

private ComponentName mAdminName = null;

public final void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mAdminName = new ComponentName(this, AdminManageReceiver.class);

    DevicePolicyManager mDevicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);

    if (!mDevicePolicyManager.isAdminActive(mAdminName)) {
        showAdminManagement();
    }

    if (mDevicePolicyManager.isAdminActive(mAdminName)) {
        mDevicePolicyManager.lockNow();
    }
    else {
        Log.e("screenlock", "Unable to lock the phone D:");
    }

    finish();
}

private void showAdminManagement() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mAdminName);
    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,
            R.string.desc_enable_admin);
    startActivityForResult(intent, ENABLE_ADMIN);

}
```

}

> Appwidgetprovider.java

```
public class NewAppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
private static final int ADMIN_INTENT = 15;
private static final String description = "Sample Administrator description";
private DevicePolicyManager mDevicePolicyManager;
private ComponentName mComponentName;

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        //updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds[lock]);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
        RemoteViews View = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);
        View.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButton, pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, View);


    }
}
```

> AdminManageReceiver.java

public class AdminManageReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you may not be able to use a single `<receiver>` for both a `DeviceAdminReceiver` *and* an `AppWidgetProvider`. The pieces of Android that work with app widgets may not hold the `android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN` permission, blocking them from working with your `<receiver>`. Use two separate `<receiver>` elements, one for your `DeviceAdminReceiver` and one for your `AppWidgetProvider`.

Second, bear in mind that app widgets on the lockscreen was only supported on Android 4.2 through 4.4. Older and newer versions of Android do not support this feature.

Comment: i am bigner in android and i put second reciver but not work plz edit my code and correction thanks for reply